# localized strings from Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, localization

My app is built with Delphi 5. Now I need to localize it. I notice many strings are standard strings come from Delphi. I think they should already have localized version, such as German version. If yes, then how to find out them?

Thanks

Alan

Comment: They should be in `Consts.pas` unit.

Comment: You should check Translation Repository.

Comment: @Free Consulting: What is this "Translation Repository" you are talking about? If it's a web site, care to give us a link? Or is it the Translation Repository used by the Delphi Translateion Manager?

Comment: @dummzeuch, Delphi the Greek city or Delphi the development package? :-) Just the same odds for the [latter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Translation_Repository).

Comment: @FreeConsulting call me stupid, but I don't understand your answer.

Comment: In "Translation Repository" of Delphi, you can find standard localized strings, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Translation_Repository